# How can I replace multiple substrings with strings from multiple related arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

In JS, I am trying to manipulate a long plain string. I want to add new chars to each match inside the string in order to make a new string. I mean there are multiple values of the searched substring inside the long string. Any ideas?

```
const string = "I am living in London.
I am living in Brighton.
I am living in Birmingham.
I am living in Paris.
I am living in Lyon.
I am living in Hamburg.
I am living in Berlin.
I am living in Münih."

const citiesGermany = [Berlin, Hamburg, Bonn, Bochum, Bremen, Münih, ...]
const citiesFrance = [Lyon, Paris, Nice, ...]
const citiesEngland = [London, Brighton, Birmingham, ...]
```

Every city inside the string, I want to replace its country. I mean the output will be:

```
newString = "I am living in England.
I am living in England.
I am living in England.
I am living in France.
I am living in France.
I am living in Germany.
I am living in Germany.
I am living in Germany."
```

Comment: Please provide an example input and outputs.

Comment: @code I made edition

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're expected to make an effort and show your code. Substring replacement is widely covered on SO already.

Comment: @isherwood Sorry, but since the question was complicated, I couldn't combine it up in my mind with the right words. Therefore I couldn't point to the exact question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const string = `I am living in London.
I am living in Brighton.
I am living in Birmingham.
I am living in Paris.
I am living in Lyon.
I am living in Hamburg.
I am living in Berlin.
I am living in Münih.`

const countryToCity = {
  'Germany': ['Berlin', 'Hamburg', 'Bonn', 'Bochum', 'Bremen', 'Münih'],
  'France': ['Lyon', 'Paris', 'Nice'],
  'England': ['London', 'Brighton', 'Birmingham']
}

let newString = string;

Object.entries(countryToCity).forEach(([country, cities]) => 
  cities.forEach(city => newString = newString.replaceAll(city, country))
)

console.log(newString)
```

Comment: can you look again to the updated question now?

Comment: @JeremyFc answer updated

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through every city and try to replace it in the string (I rearranged your cities list to make it less messy):

```js
const replace = (str, countries) => (
  Object.entries(countries).forEach(
    ([country, cities]) => cities.forEach(
      city => str = str.replaceAll(city, country)
    )
  ),
  str
)

const string = `I am living in London.
I am living in Brighton.
I am living in Birmingham.
I am living in Paris.
I am living in Lyon.
I am living in Hamburg.
I am living in Berlin.
I am living in Münih.`

const countries = {
  Germany: ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Bonn", "Bochum", "Bremen", "Münih"],
  France: ["Lyon", "Paris", "Nice"],
  England: ["London", "Brighton", "Birmingham"]
}

console.log(replace(string, countries))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is correct like the other two both. I am accepting the first answer as correct since all are correct. I am very gratefull and appreciate your kind effort.
Best regards..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append to certain text fragments, regardless of whether they are in lower or upper case you would need to use a regular expression with the flags `g` and `i` and use the group braces (`(` and `)`) to represent each encountered occurrence:

```js
const s = 'Any you can do I can do better. I can do any better than you! '

console.log(s.replace(/(any)/gi, '$1thing'))
```

**update**

Ok, the updated question turns out to be significantly different from what it seemed to be in the beginning.

```js
const string = `I am living in London.
I am living in Brighton.
I am living in Birmingham.
I am living in Paris.
I am living in Lyon.
I am living in Hamburg.
I am living in Berlin.
I am living in München.`;

const res=Object.entries({
 Germany:"Berlin,Hamburg,Bonn,Bochum,Bremen,München",
 France:"Lyon,Paris,Nice",
 England:"London,Brighton,Birmingham"}).reduce((str,[cntr,twns])=>(
// apply several replace operations on str:
  twns.split(",").forEach(twn=>str=str.replaceAll(twn,cntr)),str),string);

console.log(res);
// show the unchanged original string:
console.log(string);
```

The code you provided was syntactically not correct in several places.
The above snippet is my attempt in turning it into something that actually works. The key segment of the script is the `.reduce()` function that repeatedly replaces each town name `twn` in `str` with the country `cntr` it belongs to. The original string `string` is left unchanged.

Comment: can you look again to the updated question now?

Comment: Thank you brother, I appreciate your kind effort. your answer is correct like the other two both. I am accepting the first answer as correct since all of your answers are correct.